# Dissapearing navigation bar when pop to root view controller

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

When I click logout button I want to back to my first view controller in app, which has login register button. But when I do this, I lost my navigation bar in loginVC and registerVC (but when I log in successfully navigation bar works properly). I have tried to do it with code

```
 @IBAction func logoutButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
      
        self.navigationController?.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)

        do {
            try firebaseAuth.signOut()
        } catch let signOutError as NSError {
            print("Error signing out: %@", signOutError)
        }
    }
```

But I also have tried to do this with unwind segue. In both cases I lost my navigation bar in loginVC and registerVC. When I reset my app everything is great, I have my navigation bar again.

Here is structure of storyboards

[image]

And my storyboard with logout button is on the end of one this storyboard references.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try by adding this code in your root view Controller's viewWillAppear method

```
self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
```